# Allow only Admin role to access plugin settings/options page

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I have created a plugin, but it seems that all roles (Contributor, Author, Editor, Admin) except Subscriber have access to the settings/options page for my plugin.

How do I set permissions for only Admin to be able to access my plugin options/settings page?

EDIT: Here is how I create the options page:

```
function myplugin_add_admin_settings_menu() {
  add_options_page( 'MyPlugin Options', 'MyPlugin Options', 'read', 'myplugin-options', 'myplugin_options' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myplugin_add_admin_settings_menu' );

function myplugin_options() {
  //Display options/settings page here
}
```

Comment: show us how you create this setting page

Comment: @mmm I have added details on how I create the page above. Thxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd argument of [`add_options_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) is the capability required for this page to be displayed to the user.

Then to allow only admin to use this page, you have to set a capability which is only owned by admin, like `activate_plugins`.

So change `read` to `activate_plugins` like this:

```
add_options_page( 'MyPlugin Options', 'MyPlugin Options', 'activate_plugins', 'myplugin-options', 'myplugin_options' );
```

Comment: If you add a piece of code as example, your answer would be complete.

Comment: juste change `"read"` in your code by `"activate_plugins"`